# Multiple Django Apps with Single AWS MySQL RDS - Same Models.py Files Required

Tags: mysql, django, amazon-web-services, django-models, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Does every app connecting to a singular AWS MySQL RDS db need to have exactly the same data model?  This is a question about some tables being defined (consistently) across all apps and some tables only being defined in the app which they will be utilized while not being defined at all in others.

I am building a system that has 3 Django apps.

- One app is largely backend (i.e., api, celery jobs, etc)
- One app is an admin/ operator interface
- One app is the true user interface to the db

I know one RDS MySQL db can have connections from multiple apps if I set the security groups appropriately.  But does the data model of each app have to be the same.

For example, I use OAUTH 2 in the backend app.  Do I need to define that in the other two apps if they don't require OAUTH 2?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, so we need to combine the applications for good practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is fine technically, but probably bad practice.  We implemented the solution, but we ended up using a master infrastructure EC2 instance to handle the total framework and then plugged different Elastic Beanstalk instances into the RDS primarily associated with that infrastructure EC2 instance.